# Another exception was thrown: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<CommentList>' of 'function result'

Tags: string, dart, exception

i was add all Parameter but it was unexpected to this the Terminal
say "Another exception was thrown: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' of 'function result'" to me so what is this ._.

i have no skill about logic it's my practice work somebody please help me
thank you.

> > image [image]

here is my code

```
 class CommentsPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      createState() => CommentsPageState();
    }
    
    class CommentsPageState extends State<CommentsPage> {
      List<CommentList> _comments = [
        CommentList(
          commentContent: "Hello, desuka",
        ),
        CommentList(commentContent: "How have you been?"),
        CommentList(
          commentContent: "Hey desuka, I am doing fine dude. wbu?",
        ),
        CommentList(
          commentContent: "ehhhh, doing OK.",
        ),
        CommentList(commentContent: "Is there any thing wrong?"),
      ];
      var txt = TextEditingController();
      void _addComment(CommentList val) {
        setState(() {
          _comments.add(val);
        });
      }
    
      Widget _buildCommentList() {
        return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _comments.length) {
            return _buildCommentItem(_comments[index].toString());
          }
        });
      }
    
      Widget _buildCommentItem(String comment) {
        return ListTile(title: Text(comment));
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: header2(context),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: _buildCommentList()),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/raw/master/2.jpeg'),
                  ),
                  title: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Write comment here...",
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: OutlineButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _addComment(CommentList(commentContent: ""));
                        },
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        child: Text(
                          "Comment",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: txt,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ));
      }
    }
```

this is my code may it's help you to know what is problem on this

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      CommentsPageState._comments (package:alpha/pages/comment.page.dart)
#1      CommentsPageState._buildCommentList.<anonymous closure> (package:alpha/pages/comment.page.dart:38:19)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:455:22)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1201:28)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1145:67)
#5      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:257:30)
#6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1187:24)
#7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1124:7)
#8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#9      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#11     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#15     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5503:32)
#16     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6105:17)
#17     _ViewportElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:228:11)
#18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#28     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#30     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#32     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#36     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#38     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#41     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#43     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#45     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#46     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#47     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#49     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#50     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#51     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#52     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#53     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#54     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#55     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#56     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#57     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5503:32)
#58     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6105:17)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#61     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#62     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#63     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#64     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#66     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#67     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#68     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#69     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#70     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#71     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#72     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#73     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#74     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#75     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#76     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#77     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#78     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#79     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#80     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#82     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5503:32)
#83     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6105:17)
#84     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#85     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#86     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#88     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#90     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#91     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#92     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#93     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#94     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#95     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#96     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#97     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#98     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#99     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#100    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#101    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#102    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#103    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#104    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#105    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#107    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#108    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#109    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#110    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#111    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#112    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#113    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#114    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#115    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#116    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#117    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#118    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#119    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#120    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#121    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#122    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#123    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#124    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#125    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#126    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#127    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#128    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#129    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#130    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#131    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#132    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#133    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#134    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#135    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#136    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#137    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#138    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#139    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#140    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#141    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#142    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#143    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#144    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#145    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#146    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5503:32)
#147    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6105:17)
#148    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#149    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#150    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#151    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#152    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#153    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#154    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#155    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#156    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#157    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#158    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#159    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#160    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#161    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#162    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#163    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#164    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#165    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#166    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#167    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#168    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#169    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#170    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#171    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#172    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#173    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#174    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#175    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#176    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#177    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#178    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#179    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#180    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#181    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#182    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#183    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#184    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#185    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#186    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#187    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#188    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#189    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:181:11)
#190    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#191    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#192    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#193    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#194    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#195    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#196    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#197    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#198    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#199    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#200    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#201    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#202    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#203    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#204    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#205    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#206    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#207    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#208    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#209    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#210    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#211    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#212    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#213    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#214    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#215    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#216    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#217    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#218    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#219    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#220    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#221    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#222    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#223    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#224    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#225    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#226    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#227    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#228    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#229    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#230    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#231    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#232    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#233    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#234    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#235    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#236    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#237    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#238    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#239    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#240    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#241    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#242    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2694:33)
#243    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:873:21)
#244    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#245    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#246    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
        
Reloaded 0 libraries in 286ms.
```

Another exception was thrown: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' of 'function result'

Comment: Where does the exception originate from? Do you have the full stack trace?

Comment: Please attach full stack trace from your terminal to determine exact place where the exception is raised. Probably the problem is in `_buildCommentItem(_comments[index].toString())`, try to change this to `_buildCommentItem(_comments[index].commentContent)`. But without full error stack trace it's difficult to determine cause of the error.

Comment: @tomerpacific i was added to my post already now :)

Comment: @mrfox i was added to my post already now :)